# How can I open kontact without having to enter a kdewallet password each time?

Tags: kubuntu, password, kwallet, akonadi, kontact

I use Kubuntu 17.04 with akonadictl 5.4.3  Each time I boot Kubuntu a dialog box says,

"akonadi_imap_resource.2 (or kontact) has requested to open the wallet 'kdewallet'

I enter my password and the dialog box goes away.  How can I set up akonadictl or kontact to login automatically?

Comment: it is logging in automatically. Your passwords are stored in the encrypted keyring (kwallet) which has to be unlocked by you entering your password

Comment: Is it possible to set up so that I don't have to enter my wallet password.  Or is this not advisable.  A link to current good security practices might be useful.

Comment: The good security practice is to have all passwords stored in an encrypted wallet which can only be unlocked by you entering the password at the terminal. I don't know the exact procedure, but it is possible to set a passwordless keyring.

Comment: That's a good enough answer for me. I'll stick with one wallet password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is answered here:

[How can I open Skype without entering a keyring password each time?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/962733/how-can-i-open-skype-without-entering-a-keyring-password-each-time?noredirect=1#comment1540534_962733)